# How to find the number of rows in a table in greenplum without using count(*)

Tags: database, greenplum

```
Select count(*) from table;
```

It takes too much time to perform i want the number of rows in a table from any system table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query for approximate row count.

```
select reltuples from pg_class WHERE relname = 'table1';
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the exact row count.

Comment: Other than pg_class, count(*) is the only option to get the number of rows in a table. If it is taking more time, perform vacuum and analyze operation on table. Also check if the table data is distributed properly